# delete an element style in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
OldFunc = window.onload;
window.onload = OnLoad;

function OnLoad(){
    try{

        var pathName = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();

        //alert(pathName);
        if( pathName.indexOf("something")!=-1)
        {           
            OnFixFontAndTable();
            alert(pathName);
        }   
        OldFunc();
    }
    catch(e) 
    {
        alert(e);
    }
} 

function OnFixFontAndTable()
{
    //$('body').attr('style','');   
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').style="";
}
```

I would like to use that code snip to delete the body's style in a page but when I run the page, I keeps getting teh error 
"TypeError OldFunc is not a function"

I feed my URL address bar as `"localhost:8080/pages/something.php"`

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @VisioN: I rolled back; OP has some commented out jQuery syntax. Also, it might clue us in to OP being open to a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your first line to:

```
var OldFunc = window.onload || function() {};
```

If `window.onload` is `undefined`, and you try calling it, you will get that error. The code above will assign an empty function to `OldFunc` in the case where `window.onload` is `undefined`, so when you try calling `OldFunc()` in `OnLoad()` it won't fail.

Alternatively, let jQuery handle the event for you by specifying an `onDomReady` event. Replace the first two lines of your code with this:

```
$(function() {
    OnLoad();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you explained it there by urself. There is no function named OldFunc in your CodeSnippet.

try

```
$(document).ready(OnLoad);

function OnLoad(){
    try{

        var pathName = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();

        //alert(pathName);
        if( pathName.indexOf("something")!=-1)
        {           
            OnFixFontAndTable();
            alert(pathName);
        }   
    }
    catch(e) 
    {
        alert(e);
    }
} 

function OnFixFontAndTable()
{
    //$('body').attr('style','');   
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').style="";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move OnFixFontAndTable on top "OnLoad" and try again